# LNLN Motion Sensor - Replacing Switch, Help with RED wire

Tags: switch, motion-sensor

I purchased a motion sensor to operate the lights in my garage. The Motion sensor has four terminals labeled LNLN. When I remove the switch, I have a Black wire, white wire, bare wire, and a RED wire which is puzzling me.

The instructions are below.[image: Motion sensor instructions LNLN]  The red wire is confusing me.  Thanks for your Help
2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBCqw.png)

Comment: Are you in the US or elsewhere?  Can you take a photo of the switch that shows all the wires?

Comment: I'm in the USA, and I'll get a pic asap.

Comment: @MicahCarver -- what make and model is said motion sensor?

Answer (score 2):

Normally Black is the hot supply or L, the white is the neutral N both from the supply and to the load the red wire is the switched hot. This is how all the motion sensors work that I have installed. But you don’t show which wire is red but this is the most common. Most electricians use Red as a switched hot but it is not a requirement to do so.

Comment: Ok, so where do I tie in the switched hot Red wire? I am removing a switch to install the microwave motion sensor in the switch's place.

Comment: The red switched goes to the load black if colors were followed.